# If statement cannot recognize my text from reading a file

Tags: vb.net

I am reading all the text from a file into a array. I am doing an `if` statement to compare the string I collected from the specific array. But not able to read. I use debug and it just skip over to next if statement.

Below is my code :

```vb
Public Sub CheckConfig()
    Dim data1 = My.Computer.FileSystem.ReadAllText("C:\DataCollection\Config.cfg")

    'Read All Text
    Dim quoteArray As New ArrayList
    FileOpen(1, "C:\DataCollection-PPTC\Config.cfg", OpenMode.Input)
    Do While Not EOF(1)
        quoteArray.Add(LineInput(1))
    Loop
    FileClose(1)

    'Hardward Selection
    HardwareSelectionLocation = InStr(quoteArray(1), "=")
    HardwareSelection = Mid(quoteArray(1), HardwareSelectionLocation + 1)

    If HardwareSelection = "Modbus TCP" Then
        HaiwellCPUPort = True
        lblConnectionType.Text = "Modbus TCP"
    Else
        HaiwellCPUPort = False
    End If

    If HardwareSelection = "RS232 Module" Then
        HaiwellRS232Module = True
        lblConnectionType.Text = "RS232 Module"
    Else
        HaiwellRS232Module = False
    End If

End Sub
```

Data inside the config file :

```
#Hardware Selection :Modbus TCP or Modbus RS232 or RS232 Module or Wireless Module or USB Port
Hardware Selection = Modbus RS232
```

Comment: Any extra whitespace or a casing difference? When debugging, what *is* the value?

Comment: Simply debugging and inspecting the variables before hitting the if statement should let you know what's happening. Check the actual value of `HardwareSelection` and see if it is what you (and the code) expects it to be.

Comment: You could replace all that vb6 code before the `if-Then-Else` blocks with just: `Dim HardwareSelection = System.IO.File.ReadLines("C:\DataCollection-PPTC\Config.cfg").Skip(1).FirstOrDefault?.Split({"="}, StringSplitOptions.RemoveEmptyEntries).LastOrDefault?.Trim`.

Comment: If they are not being determined to be equal then they are not equal. It's that simple. Debug your code. Set a breakpoint and examine the actual value your code is generating instead of assuming that it is working as it should, even when the code tells you it's not. If the strings still look the same then obviously it's something that you can't see just by looking at the text, so get the Unicode value for each character and compare them. This is all the sort of stuff you need to do BEFORE you post here.

Comment: Why do you read all the text out of one file (into data1) and then not use it, and then go and read all the text out of another file (in a much more hard work way)?

Answer (score 1):

We can make your config reading code a bit more self explanatory and simpler:

```
Public Sub CheckConfig()


    Dim lines = IO.File.ReadAllLines("C:\DataCollection-PPTC\Config.cfg")

    For Each line In lines 

      Dim bits = line.Split({"="c},2) 'Split to at most 2: "X=Y=Z" -> "X","Y=Z"

      If bits(0).StartsWith("Hardware Selection") Then
          lblConnectionType.Text = bits(1).TrimStart()
          HaiwellCPUPort = bits(1).Contains("Modbus TCP")
          HaiwellRS232Module = bits(1).Contains("RS232 Module")
      End If

      'To support other config lines copypaste the block above and change the
      'strings inside StartsWith/Contains, the lblConnectionType labels and the HaiwellXx variables as appropriate 

    Next line 
End Sub
```

Answer (score 0):

`HardwareSelectionLocation = InStr(quoteArray(1), "=")`
With this line you are taking out the data after "=" sign but as per your example,

```
Hardware Selection = Modbus RS232
```

After "=" sign there is a space it seems. 
just check for any space before or after the expected data.